# SVN info from ASP.NET : 'Can't determine the user's config path'

Tags: asp.net, svn, appdata

Got an ASP.NET site which I wish to perform an SVN info call from.

My understanding is this error message appears when a user hasn't yet done their basic setup to use SVN.  Specifically there is a folder a few steps under AppData named Subversion which when not present and properly configured, shows the aforementioned message.

The ASP.NET site is running under the account "NetworkService" whose AppData folder I cannot find.  I was planning to copy & paste the Subversion folder, as it's not easy to do an actual log in as NetworkService.

How can I proceed using NetworkService so that the "svn info" can also proceed?

Thanks in advance--

FYI: Using SharpSvn as a wrapper.  Doubt that matters, but there you go

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add this line before you authenticate and or perform any svn event.

```
client.LoadConfiguration(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Svn"), true);
```

Comment: You might also have to clear the authentication, depending on where you installed Tortoise.  TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data > Authentication data > click "Clear"

Comment: An answer worthy of MacGyver for sure.

Comment: Once again MacGyver saves the day!